# How to merge two models in django

Tags: django-models

I have two models with foreign key.

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    town = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(SpaUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  #My foreign key
    contact = SpaUser.objects.filter(email= 'owner').values('firstname ') # I want to access SpaUser.firstname to display in django admin


class SpaUser(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

I use Ad.contact in Ad model to acess SpaUser.firstname in Spauser model but i can't.
Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `contact` a property instead (and you should make use of the foreign key `owner` instead of filtering from another queryset of `SpaUser`):

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    @property
    def contact(self):
        return self.owner.firstname
```

Comment: Thanks you. It's works. I add self.owner.firstname instead of owner.firstname